# "true" messes up escape code handling in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I was observing something strange in my Powershell script just now and I finally narrowed it down to a bug in my code, it was this line:

```
$AnyExecuted = true
```

It should've been

```
$AnyExecuted = $true
```

However, this line messes up escape code handling in both the standaline Powershell Core windows on Windows 10, as well as in the Windows Terminal:

[image: messed up prompt]

Anyone know why this happens? What is the `true` expression? I can't find any mention of it, and why would it have this effect on the output from Powershell?

Note, obviously I updated my script to use $true, which was what I intended, this question is just about what `true` is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When executing

```
$AnyExecuted = $true
```

`$AnyExecuted` will be of type `Boolean` and your script may run as expected. If you execute

```
$AnyExecuted = true
```

instead and no error is thrown, then there is an alias, cmdlet or executable available that has the name `true`. It will not be available on default Windows 10 installations.

As it does not throw an error on your side, you might have `true` somehow available. You can check for that with `Get-Command true`. Using a MinGW environment, makes `true.exe` available, for example.

Using the result of your still unknown `true` "thing" may indeed lead to unexpected behaviour. To investigate on the result of `true` you can evaluate `(true).GetType()` on your system.

Comment: Yep, your answer contains more details about how to troubleshoot the problem than my own so I deleted mine and accepted yours. I had Cygwin installed, which had `true.exe`.

Comment: And couple that with my lack of understanding of what happens if I do `If (FunctionCall)` that also outputs if there's anything that was done, it seemed to work as it should.